# Why are there only black and white points in my recursive graph, and no gray points? Is this related to the selection of the threshold value?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I used PyCharm2023.2.3 to generate the recurrence plot.
Here is my code and the result of my recurrence plot--Figure 1.
Figure 2 is the result of four eigenvalues of recursive quantitative analysis,based on the recursion graph I drew.
I want my recurrence image to have the same gray area as Figure 3. I don't know if it's the code or the threshold or the data.

Figure 3 is what I want it to look like.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyts.image import RecurrencePlot

# 数据
years = [1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1972, 1975, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
publications = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 21, 26, 50, 112, 158, 247, 331, 399, 442, 476, 495, 558, 499, 662, 745, 729, 821, 853, 975, 1315, 1724, 1986, 2347, 2712, 2974, 3193, 3557, 3356, 3305, 3139, 3237, 3325, 3396, 3466, 3963, 5946, 11535, 19469, 25161, 27784, 28135, 25867, 23622]
data = np.array(publications)

# 相空间重构
embedding_dim = 2  # 嵌入维度
delay = 1  # 延迟时间
embedded_data = np.column_stack([data[i:i+embedding_dim] for i in range(len(data)-delay*(embedding_dim-1))])

# 递归图
rp = RecurrencePlot(threshold='point', percentage=20) # 选择了“point”作为阈值类型，并设定了百分之10的阈值。这意味着如果两个点之间的距离小于整个数据集距离的10%，则将它们认为是相似的。
X_rp = rp.fit_transform(embedded_data)

# 绘制递归图
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.imshow(X_rp[0], cmap='binary', origin='lower')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('Recurrence Plot')
plt.colorbar(label='Recurrence')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
# 计算递归率、递归信息熵、确定性和层状性
# 递归率
recurrence_rate = np.sum(X_rp) / (X_rp.shape[0] * X_rp.shape[1])
# 递归信息熵
recurrence_entropy = -np.log(1 / X_rp.shape[1])

# 计算递归图的层次熵
def compute_hierarchy_entropy(rp):
    recurrence_matrix = rp[0]  # 获取递归图矩阵

    # 计算每一列的非零元素数量，即每个时间步的递归点数
    num_recurrences = np.count_nonzero(recurrence_matrix, axis=0)

    # 将递归点数转换为概率分布
    prob_distribution = num_recurrences / np.sum(num_recurrences)

    # 计算层次熵
    hierarchy_entropy = -np.sum(prob_distribution * np.log2(prob_distribution))

    return hierarchy_entropy

# 调用函数计算递归图的层次熵
hierarchy_entropy = compute_hierarchy_entropy(X_rp)


# 确定性：
def calculate_determinism(X_rp, threshold):
    diagonal_sum = np.sum(np.diagonal(X_rp, offset=1))
    total_sum = np.sum(X_rp)
    determinism = diagonal_sum / total_sum
    return determinism

determinism = calculate_determinism(X_rp, threshold=0.1)


print("Recurrence Rate:", recurrence_rate)
print("Recurrence Entropy:", recurrence_entropy)
print("Determinism:", determinism)
print("Hierarchy entropy:", hierarchy_entropy)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just for a starter guess: try changing the dtype of your input to np.float. `year` and `publications` are currently all integers, and I don't know how `RecurrencePlot` handles that, but potentially, all operations may be integer operations and the result is also of integer type.

Comment: Please share more information `X_rp[0]`. As @9769953 points out, it may be an integer array, which you can check by printing out `embedded_data.dtype` and `X_rp[0].dtype`. If that is the issue, trying changing the `embedded_data` array to floats before operating on it.

Comment: `cmap='binary'`  . . . .

Comment: @D.L Check the colorbar on the image: it's greyscale. The [Matplotlib documentations also shows](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html#sequential2) that binary is greyscale; perhaps the color scheme is a a misnomer, but the colormap choice doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @9769953 Thanks for your advise. I replaced the integer array with a decimal array following the tips you gave me, but it still didn't work. It bothers me. If possible, I would also like to know how the threshold is determined when building a recursive graph.